# Stuck in Python with **kwargs

Tags: python

I need to create a function with `**kwargs`, which should double the numeric values in my dictionary. Only numeric values!

My code looks like this:

```
fmm= {'zbk': 30,
        'moartea': 78,
        'Cox': 'sweet',
        'fanina': 'Alex',
        'rex': 24
        }

def my_func(**kwargs):
   for k,v in fmm.items():
     print(v*2)
my_func()
```

Comment: Why must it use **kwargs?

Comment: Should those values be doubled within the dictionary? Also test v for the int datatype by using type() or int() within try... except...

Comment: I don t know do you have any idea how to solve this.

Comment: You know, that you are referring to the global Variable fmm instead of kwargs?

Comment: Clearly, you are missing something. Why should `**kwargs` be used?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this:

```
fmm= {'zbk': 30,
        'moartea': 78,
        'Cox': 'sweet',
        'fanina': 'Alex',
        'rex': 24
        }

def my_func(**kwargs):

    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        if isinstance(v,int) or isinstance(v,float):
            kwargs[k] *= 2
    return kwargs

fmm = my_func(**fmm)
print(fmm)
```

Note that I wasn't able to directly change the arguments; Python makes a copy of the passed dict.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: Why check for `int`?   Floats support `* 2` and it is perfectly valid for a string (and some other objects too).  It might be worth checking is the object supports `__mul__`.

Comment: the OP asked for "doubling numeric values". Well, floats should be checked too. But strings are out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Why the double pointer? You can do perfectly without it too.

```
fmm= {'zbk': 30,
        'moartea': 78,
        'Cox': 'sweet',
        'fanina': 'Alex',
        'rex': 24
        }

def my_func():
   for k,v in fmm.items():
     print(v*2)
my_func()
```

Comment: This is probably a tutorial exercise on keyword argument unpacking.